# Inconsistent Accessibility in Lists c#

Tags: c#, list

I'm following an RPG c# tutorial, and have come across this error. It is not explained in the tutorial, and I'm unsure what i did wrong.

Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Engine
{
    public class Monster : LivingCreature
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MaximumDamage { get; set; }
        public int RewardExperiencePoints { get; set; }
        public int RewardGold { get; set; }
        
        public List<LootItem> LootTable { get; set; }

        public Monster(int id, string name, int maximumDamage, int rewardExperiencePoints, int rewardGold, int currentHitPoints, int maximumHitPoints) : base (currentHitPoints, maximumHitPoints)
        {
            ID = id;
            Name = name;
            MaximumDamage = maximumDamage;
            RewardExperiencePoints = rewardExperiencePoints;
            RewardGold = rewardGold;

            LootTable = new List<LootItem>();
                
        }
    }
}
```

The problem lies in: `public List<LootItem> LootTable { get; set; }`

I get the error message: "Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'List' is less accessible than property 'Monster.LootTable'"

I also get the same error message in another class, but if I can fix this one, i can hopefully fix the other.

Comment: what is living creature?

Comment: Try making LootTable be just a member rather than a property, i.e. remove the getter and setter piece of code.

Comment: @JBKing nothing changed, still the same problem.

Comment: @PenguinBlast does LivingCreature has same LootItem?

Comment: @Sajeetharan what do you mean? Do you mean if it has the same properties of LootItem? If so, no. The LivingCreature has only 2 properties, "maxHitPoints" and "currentHitPoints".

Comment: Probably `LootItem` is not public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the LootItem class public,

```
public class LootItem
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: How do i do that? Sorry, I'm new to Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you want me to post it in the comments here?